# How can I find the best sellers by grouping stock units in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pdo, eloquent

I am trying to select the best selling items based on how many stock units have been created on that product. The more stock units on the product = the more sales.

My product_list table looks like this:

```
Schema::create('product_list', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->decimal('cost', 9, 2)->default(00.00);
    $table->integer('product_category')->unsigned();            # IE Bespoke/Static/Dynamic
    $table->integer('product_type')->unsigned();                # IE Themes(Custom Or Not)/Number of pages
    $table->integer('product_score')->default(0);               # How many favourites does it have?
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

    $table->index(array('product_category', 'product_type'));

    $table->foreign('product_category')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
    $table->foreign('product_type')->references('id')->on('product_types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

My products_skus table looks like this:

```
Schema::create('product_skus', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('reference');
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

    $table->index(array('product_id'));

    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('product_list')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Here is what I have tried so far using Eloquent - not too fussed about getting any other joins in at the moment, just getting the best sellers working:

```
$topSellers = DB::table('product_list')->join('product_skus', 'product_skus.product_id', '=', 'product_list.id')
                                       ->groupBy('product_skus.product_id')
                                       ->limit(5)
                                       ->get()
                                       ->all();
```

Which is giving me this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'iezonsolutions.product_list.id' isn't in GROUP BY (42000)

How can I find the top sold items? I create an SKU on every product_item when its sold which is a way of tracking the top sellers as well as giving the user a unique tracking ability.

**Update to show relations**

`product_skus` has a foreign key `product_id` which relates to `product_list` table column `id`. I want to group the stock keeping units based on the relation o the products id. The most SKU's grouped to that single product id, I want to get them products from the `product_list` table

```
$topSellers = DB::table('product_skus')->join('product_list', 'product_skus.product_id', '=', 'product_list.id')
                                       ->orderBy('product_skus.product_id')
                                       ->limit(5)
                                       ->get()
                                       ->all();
```

Is now grouping the correct relations, however, it is giving me an output of

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#725 ▼
    +"id": 2
    +"reference": "A400IEZON_"
    +"product_id": 2
    +"created_at": "2019-01-16 16:37:16"
    +"updated_at": "2019-01-16 16:37:16"
    +"cost": "100.00"
    +"product_category": 1
    +"product_type": 2
    +"product_score": 0
    +"rating": 0
    +"down_payment": "10.00"
  }
  1 => {#726 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"reference": "C400IEZON_"
    +"product_id": 3
    +"created_at": "2019-01-16 16:37:25"
    +"updated_at": "2019-01-16 16:37:25"
    +"cost": "150.00"
    +"product_category": 1
    +"product_type": 3
    +"product_score": 0
    +"rating": 0
    +"down_payment": "10.00"
  }
  2 => {#727 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"reference": "C400IEZON_"
    +"product_id": 3
    +"created_at": "2019-01-16 16:37:25"
    +"updated_at": "2019-01-16 16:37:25"
    +"cost": "150.00"
    +"product_category": 1
    +"product_type": 3
    +"product_score": 0
    +"rating": 0
    +"down_payment": "10.00"
  }
]
```

I want to count all of these, so here, product with the `id` 3 should be shown as the top product followed by product 2.

Comment: Do you have any kind of relationship between product_list and product_skus (the models)?

Comment: No, `product_skus` has the relation to the `product_list`. But, I want to first select all of the `product_skus` with the most relations to a product, then select the top 5 products - Saying it like that, I think I need 2 separate queries @Mozammil

Comment: Could you post the relations? It would be easier to show you :)

Comment: Updated the question, thanks @Mozammil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with a Sub Query.

```
$skus = ProductSku::selectRaw('COUNT(*)')
    ->whereColumn('product_id', 'product_list.id')
    ->getQuery();

$products = ProductList::select('*')
    ->selectSub($skus, 'skus_count')
    ->orderBy('skus_count', 'DESC')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

This would be a lot easier if `ProductList` had a relationship with `ProductSku`. 
Then you could just do this:

For example in `App\ProductList`, you could have something like this:

```
public function skus()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductSku::class);
}
```

.. then, your query would simply be:

```
ProductList::withCount('skus') 
    ->orderBy('skus_count', 'DESC')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

.. which will produce the same query as above. I am not entirely sure about your model names. You should change it accordingly.

Comment: Thank-you **so** much! I used the first solution just simply due to my infrastructure in the DB. This gives me my exact expected output! I will mark as soon as I can